# Android app launch

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm begginer at programming for Android. Decided to write app in Xamarin on C#.
I have axml with complete design. In MainActivity I have this:

```
ImageButton logoButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.logoButton);
    ImageButton cartButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.cartButton);
    ImageButton privateButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.privateButton);
    ImageButton homeButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.homeButton);
    ImageButton nextButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.nextButton);
    ImageButton previousButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.previousButton);
```

This code - reference to the controls that i have in axml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. Now you can change the text of the buttons:

```
cartbutton.setText("...")
```

or set a buttonlistener:

```
cartbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClicklistener(..){
```

Comment: glad I could help. one minor addition. In xamarin with c# it is of course capital letters: SetText and SetOn...   
would be happy if you could accept this answer.